withTimeout from R.utils doesn't work on Linux/Ubuntu
I am trying to migrate a simple R script from Windows to Linux and it simply doesn't work on Linux.
Here is an example:
library(R.utils)

myfun <- function(x){
  Sys.sleep(2)
  return(x*x)
}

withTimeout(myfun(2), 
                timeout = 1, 
                onTimeout=c("error"))

There is similar thread here with a suggestion to use processx.
It does not solve my problem, as my code is huge and requires a different setup.
R.utils::withTimeout, works differently on Linux than in Windows
Hope a solution exists...
Below a screenshot of my Ubuntu 20 with R 4.3.3


From what I've read here there shouldn't be an issue with Linux, as the package does test on that OS. That being said: do you have the latest version of R.util? I normally run on a Mac, but just for you, I went on my Kali, it had been a while so I had to update...well, everything. The code in your question worked the same as it did on my Mac--- as I would have expected it. Perhaps you're expecting a different outcome?

I added a screenshot to the main post.

I get the appropriate error when I run this code on Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS and R version 4.3.2.  Maybe update R.util and restart your R session.

This also doesn't work on my ubuntu on AWS
